# How to start a hosted network automatically?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wifi

I want to start hosted network automatically at startup.

My question is about how to make a patch file to check status of hosted network first and depending on status run a command.

Like this:

```
@ECHO OFF 

If "netsh wlan show hostednetwork|find "Status"|find "Started"= Started  Go 
To End 

If "netsh wlan show hostednetwork|find "Status"|find "Not Started"= Not 
Started  Go To Start  

:start
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
goto end

:end 
PAUSE
```

This code format is wrong. How can I write the correct patch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something more simple. The `FIND` command sets ERRORLEVEL to 1 if it does not find the pattern.

```
netsh wlan show hostednetwork | find "Status" | find "Started"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Start 
GOTO TheEnd

:Start
netsh wlan start hostednetwork

:TheEnd
pause
EXIT /B
```